# Send data via ViewData multiselect in ASP.NET Core 3.0 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I’m trying to create multiselect `DropDownList`, which should load data from the database. All fields should be selected on the first run. I'd like to send back to the controller parameter `List<string> selectedStatus`, do some logic there and send back to the view by `ViewData["Status"]`. Based on this parameter I'd like to fill multiselect `DropDownList`... I’m using jQuery select2.

On first run there is nothing in the `DropDownList` selected. 
When I select more than one option and send to controller, the first value only will appear in the `DropDownList`.

I have the Index method with the following code

```
        var status = new List<SelectListItem>();

        if (!selectedStatus.Any())
        {
            status = (from t in _context.Status
                      select new SelectListItem()
                      {
                          Text = t.Status,
                          Value = t.StatusId.ToString(),
                          Selected = true
                      }).OrderBy(t => t.Text)
                         .ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            status = (from t in _context.Status
                      select new SelectListItem()
                      {
                          Text = t.Status,
                          Value = t.StatusId.ToString(),
                          Selected = false
                      }).OrderBy(t => t.Text)
                         .ToList();

            foreach (var item in status)
            {
                if (selectedStatus.Any(s => s.Contains(item.Value)) == true)
                {
                    item.Selected = true;

                }
            }

        }

        ViewData["Status"] = status;
```

In the Index view

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <div class="input-group">
        @Html.DropDownList("selectedStatus", new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Status"], "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple", id = "select" })
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">Submit</button>
            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn   btn-outline-secondary">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
        <script>
                $('select').select2({
                    theme: 'bootstrap4',
                    multiple: true,
                });
        </script>
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What's missing there?

Thank you.

Comment: Use this link :https://forums.asp.net/t/2147941.aspx?How+to+pass+multiselect+selected+items+to+a+controller+for+filtering+records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Fabian Kamp suggested , you should use a viewmodel to contain the Status and selectedStatus. Here is a workaround that using js to selected all fields , you could refer to:

*ViewModel*

```
public class Status
{
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public string StatusName { get; set; }
}

public class StatusVM
{
    public List<string> selectedStatus { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Status { get; set; }
}
```

*Controller*

```
 public IActionResult MultiSelectDropDownList(List<string> selectedStatus)
    {
        var model = new StatusVM();

        if (!selectedStatus.Any())
        {
            model.Status = (from t in _context.Status
                      select new SelectListItem()
                      {
                          Text = t.StatusName,
                          Value = t.StatusId.ToString(),
                      }).OrderBy(t => t.Text)
                         .ToList();
            model.selectedStatus = _context.Status.Select(s => s.StatusId.ToString()).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            model.Status = (from t in _context.Status
                      select new SelectListItem()
                      {
                          Text = t.StatusName,
                          Value = t.StatusId.ToString(),
                      }).OrderBy(t => t.Text)
                         .ToList();
            model.selectedStatus = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in model.Status)
            {
                if (selectedStatus.Any(s => s.Contains(item.Value)) == true)
                {
                    model.selectedStatus.Add(item.Value);
                }
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

*View*

```
@model Demo1.Models.StatusVM

<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="MultiSelectDropDownList" method="get">
  <div class="input-group">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedStatus, new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.Status, "Value", "Text", Model.selectedStatus), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "js-example-theme-multiple", multiple = "multiple", id = "select" })
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">Submit</button>
        <a asp-action="Index" class="btn   btn-outline-secondary">Cancel</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

@section Scripts {
  @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var stringArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.selectedStatus));

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("select").select2({
                theme: "classic",
                multiple: true,
          });
          $("select").val(stringArray).trigger('change');
        });

    </script>
  }
}
```

*Result*
[image]

Reference:[Setting multiple values using jQuery select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51730090/setting-multiple-values-using-jquery-select2)

Comment: This is exactly the solution that I needed. 
It helped me. 
Thank you very much.
But I still have a question, how to add a viewmodel to an existing model?
I have some model created, of course, and your solution is to send a new viewmodel to the view.
Should I add all "old" model code to the IActionResult MultiSelectDropDownList() method or call it there? Should I add call for MultiSelectDropDownList() to the Index method?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On the first run its empty because you have a not equals char infront of your `selectedStatus.Any()` or you have accendently changed the true false in the first if, but a easier solution for this would be

```
 var status  = (from t in _context.Status
                      select new SelectListItem()
                      {
                          Text = t.Status,
                          Value = t.StatusId.ToString(),
                          Selected = !selectedStatus.Any()
                      }).OrderBy(t => t.Text)
                         .ToList();
```

without a if query.

The second thing is you should really use a ViewModel not ViewData or some thing like this  for this amount of data.