# Adding options to a datalist

Tags: html, jquery

I can select just one element from dropdown list. How to add more than one element to input separately by comma.

I need to add new value to existing value in the same fied. I mean if I select January, I can add February and the result is needed to be January, February

```js
var str = ''; // variable to store the options
var month = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
  "September", "October", "November", "December");
for (var i = 0; i < month.length; ++i) {
  str += '<option value="' + month[i] + '" />'; // Storing options in variable
}
var my_list = document.getElementById("months");
my_list.innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<input name="month" list="months">
<datalist id="months"></datalist>
```

Comment: @mplungjan this is not duplicate, as there is no answer. I have the same thing as on the link which you sent, but I need to add more values. Please check it again. I need to `ADD` value, not just select

Comment: @mplungjan, in my case I need to add new value to existing value in the same fied. I mean if I select January, I can add February and the result is needed to be `January, February`

Comment: @mplungjan could you please send an answer, because I checked all web sites from link you sent

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bhbwg0rg/1/

After each entry press ,(Comma) and then Spacebar

Comment: @mplungjan, wow! Thank you, but  last question if you don`t mind. How to make it automatically? without pressing comma and spacebar?

Comment: You need a widget. The DataList is not made to do what you want except for emails - the link I posted is from the dupe

Comment: Select2 for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51730090/setting-multiple-values-using-jquery-select2/51730206